# Show logout notice on login page only once

Tags: javascript

On a password protected website (ajax-php-jquery login system), a fadeIn/fadeOut alert confirms that the user just logged out. The user is sent back to the login page and I do a `document.referrer` to check if he comes from a page of the site (if so it means that he just logged out so I can display the message). But of course if the user refreshes the page he will get the notice again.

I was thinking of changing the `document.referrer` but the property is read-only. Any idea how I could display the message only once if the user did log out?

Comment: The pattern you are talking about is commonly called "flash notifications", Google that and you should find a number of ideas for how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a conditional with PHP:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['justLoggedOut'])){
    print '<script type="text/javascript"> ..notification code.. </script>';
    unset($_SESSION['justLoggedOut']);
}
```

You just have to set the session from within the authenticated area (or the logout page which redirects to the index page [I'm assuming.])

Comment: typically this format is extended to iterate through an array of messages, unsetting item when it's displayed.

Comment: I've tried this and successfully created a session when the user logs out like so: `session_name('justLoggedOut'); session_start();` then I used your code above but the javascript is not printed and the session remains. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try just this: `$_SESSION['justLoggedOut'] = true;`

Comment: It doesn't work either. I don't get it, I can see the session in Firebug but the conditional doesn't work... I'll find the answer by myself, I might do something wrong somewhere else? The funny thing is I tried the cookie solution as well, and the same thing is happening: The cookie is successfully created but the if statement is never verified! Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cookie would be easiest route. Simply add a cookie when they log out, and then delete it after the notification has been shown. This cookie could contain all of the information you want about the log out: e.g. the time the logged out and the URL from which they initiated the log out.

Of course, that is assuming your clients are allowing cookies on your site. A server side alternative would be to use session data. Your notification would then send an AJAX call back to the server to clear the indicator that the notification should be shown.